# CUDA 8 nvcc fails on macOS Sierra with errors in stdio.h, stdlib.h and other headers

Tags: xcode, cuda, xcode7.3, macos-sierra, xcode-command-line-tools

I have a Mac dev machine that has installed Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8.0.

After updating to CUDA 8, I set up the system to use the Xcode 7.3.1 command line tools, as Xcode 8 command line tools are currently unsupported by nvcc 8.0.

After updating the OS from OS X 10.11 El Capitan to macOS 10.12 Sierra, I am no longer able to compile a hello world program with CUDA 8.

The compilation fails, the output containing hundreds of lines of /usr/include headers, starting with:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h(133): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/stdio.h(134): error: expected a ")"

/usr/include/stdio.h(134): error: "_Nullable" has already been declared in the current scope
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and re-installed the `Command Line Tools (OS X 10.11) for Xcode 7.3.1` that seem to have been corrupted through the OS update.

nvcc 8.0 now works as intended.

Comment: Care to elaborate how you uninstalled them? Just rm -fr /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ or is there more to it? I tried that way, but still get above errors. Although that is on a complete reinstall of sierra.

Comment: I **re**-installed them. I did not remove anything, I just ran the installer again. It says "OS X 10.11" in the name, but it installs fine on 10.12.